# Is breaking a for loop for a special event a good practice?

Tags: c, for-loop

I have a general case iterating over e.g. 30 loops in a *for loop*, however, in some case I only need the information of the first loop. Thus, I break the for loop in this case.

Is this a good practice or should I combine a conditional statement and 2 *for loops* to have two independent cases?

**Typical pattern :**

```c
int i;
for(i=0; i<30; i++)
{
    //do something generic
    if(specificCase)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

**Use case :**

I use this to build a frame with 30 measurements. But sometimes I need a frame with only the first measurement.

Comment: If in some cases you only need the information from the first iteration, can you test for that *before* the `for` loop?

Comment: The fact is that I use an if in the for loop to test the case and if this is True i break. I am editing the question.

Comment: Why not just include the additional condition as part of the `for` loop conditional? E.g. `for(i=0; i<30 && !specificCase; i++)`

Comment: @Clément As you might have guessed, there is no general answer on this. It is a matter of readability. Things differ, if your code is subject to formal code verification or strict coding rules, of course.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Things can get complex, when there are code parts _before_ the break, that still should be executed, while some things after should not

Comment: Agreed, bottom line there is nothing wrong with jumping out of a `for` loop any time you need to.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I like this, I was blinded by the formal structure you see everytime in a for loop totally forgetting we could do otherwise than this "standard condition"

Comment: How you do it is really a matter of form. You can use your `for` loop and break it whenever, if you know you will loop once, you can keep a counter, `int i = 0; do { stuff; i++; } while (i < 30 && !specificCase);` you can make it a `while` loop -- bottom like is *Make it work* (worry about the style points later `:)`

Comment: Whichever makes the code most easy to read, and have no code dublicates maybe a `do{}while (!specialcase && i++<30)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specific case could be returned by a third party that's failing , a database or a messaging system for instance. If this error condition is not transient then it makes perfect sense to break out of the loop and try to reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

I was always taught that *bounded* iteration (I.E a `for` loop) should only be used when you want to iterate an exact number of times, (E.g. traverse a whole `array`) and that breaking out is generally considered bad practice.

In this scenario *unbounded* iteration should be used instead (I.E. a `while` loop). Obviously this isn't an enforced rule and just a rule of thumb but has stood me well thus far.

Obviously this could be wrong an I'm happy to be corrected.

Alternatively if you only need the information on the first, loop then why bother with the loop at all?